# How to keep side by side search box and submit button?

Tags: html, jquery-mobile

Testing in IBM Worklight

by data-inline="true" its not working?
the position is in up down but I want side by side.

```
    <div data-role="header" id="the-page" data-position="fixed">
            <h3>YUMMY</h3>

            <div data-role="navbar" id="navbar" data-iconpos="left">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#Favs" id="favs" data-icon="star">Favs</a></li>
                <li><a href="#myPanel" id="more" data-icon="bars">More</a></li><!-- PANEL LINK -->
            </ul>
        </div>

            <label for="search" id="label" style="font-weight: bold; font-style: italic; font-family: Comic Sans MS"></label>
            <input type="search" name="search" id="search" data-mini="true" placeholder="Search for Restaurants" data-theme="a" data-inline="true">
<input type="submit" value="Go" data-inline="true" id ="submit" onclick="getRestaurants()">
.....
```

screenshot link

```
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/15844249/stackoverflow/side%20by%20side%20search%20submit.png
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add an id to your submit button and remove data-inline.

```
<input type="submit" value="Go" id="submit" onclick="getRestaurants()">
```

and then add containers around your inputs.

```
 <div id ="container">
   <div id ="search_con">
    <input type="search" name="search" id="search" data-mini="true" placeholder="Search for Restaurants" data-theme="a">
   </div>
   <div id="submit_con">
    <input type="submit" value="Go" id ="submit" onclick="getRestaurants()">
   </div>
 </div>
```

and adjust the width of the container on the screen with the width of the components inside each container. Also `float` each container left so that they are side by side.

```
<script>
    #container {width:100%;}
    #submit_con {width:20%; float:left;}
    #search_con {width:80%; float:left;}
    #search {width:100%;}
    #submit {width:100%;}
</script>
```

Place this inside the `<head>` tag of your document.

http://jsfiddle.net/6opot4cs/3/